# Docker localhost error with airflow (Windows 10)

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm trying to run airflow locally with docker. But I keep running into a permission error (PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler').

I've tried running docker and VScode as administrator and also tried using icacl "C:\Users\Username \airflow\logs" /grant everyone:f

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.2.1
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.1}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

This is the error I'm getting after I run docker-compose up.
The error reoccurs for airflow-scheduler_1, airflow-webserver_1, flower_1,airflow-worker_1 .

```
airflow-triggerer_1  | ....................
airflow-triggerer_1  | ERROR! Maximum number of retries (20) reached.
airflow-triggerer_1  |
airflow-triggerer_1  | Last check result:
airflow-triggerer_1  | $ airflow db check
airflow-triggerer_1  | Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
airflow-triggerer_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1273, in mkdir
airflow-triggerer_1  |     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
airflow-triggerer_1  | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler/2021-11-16'
airflow-triggerer_1  |
airflow-triggerer_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
airflow-triggerer_1  |
airflow-triggerer_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 563, in configure
airflow-triggerer_1  |     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 736, in configure_handler
airflow-triggerer_1  |     result = factory(**kwargs)
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 47, in __init__
airflow-triggerer_1  |     Path(self._get_log_directory()).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1277, in mkdir
airflow-triggerer_1  |     self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1273, in mkdir
airflow-triggerer_1  |     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
airflow-triggerer_1  | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler'
airflow-triggerer_1  |
airflow-triggerer_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
airflow-triggerer_1  |
airflow-triggerer_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
airflow-triggerer_1  |     from airflow.__main__ import main
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
airflow-triggerer_1  |     settings.initialize()
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 483, in initialize
airflow-triggerer_1  |     LOGGING_CLASS_PATH = configure_logging()
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 74, in configure_logging
airflow-triggerer_1  |     raise e
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 69, in configure_logging
airflow-triggerer_1  |     dictConfig(logging_config)
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 800, in dictConfig
airflow-triggerer_1  |     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
airflow-triggerer_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 571, in configure
airflow-triggerer_1  |     '%r' % name) from e
airflow-triggerer_1  | ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor'
airflow-triggerer_1  |
project_5_capstone_airflow-triggerer_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks either your directory doesnt exist or you dont have a permission to access the directory, try these things

1. Check if the path exists , if not create the path using mkdir /opt/airflow/logs/scheduler
2. Run chmod 777 /opt/airflow/logs/scheduler to give all the permission to access the bucket

Let me know if that problem still exist